# Trying to update nested model first on before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, before-save

I am calculating `:price` in my nested `item model` in order to map it in my `invoice model`. The problem is that the `before_save` in the `invoice model` is being called first and I want it to be called after the `before_save` in the nested`item model`

Any ideas on how to do this?

Here are my models

invoice.rb

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :items

accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

validates :sender, presence: true

before_save :increment_invoice_number, :set_amount

private

def increment_invoice_number
    if published == true
        self.invoice_number = user.invoices.where(:published => true).count + 1
    end
end

def set_amount
    self.amount = items.map(&:price).sum(&:to_i)             
end

end
```

And  item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :invoice

 before_save :set_price

  def set_price
    self.price = cost.to_i * quantity.to_i
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `validates_associated :items` to `invoice.rb`
and then changed `before_save` in my nested model to `before_validation`
and also added `validates_presence_of :price` and this fixed it.